# Creating a Shiny app: "Error: no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "NULL""

Tags: r, shiny, screen-scraping, reddit

I asked a question not long ago about this same Shiny app, and though it's definitely starting to make a lot more sense now, I'm still hitting some roadblocks. The app is meant to crawl Twitter and Reddit, bringing back a word cloud for each. Twitter works perfectly, but Reddit will search and clean, but it won't actually create the word cloud. I'm pretty sure the problem is with setting the reddit dataset to "NULL" when the user hasn't searched yet, because the rest of the code I've used in non-Shiny form, and it's worked fine. Any help you can give I greatly appreciate!

```
#Define server logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  red_data <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)

  # Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix

  observeEvent(input$update,{

     # reddit cleaning
    red_data = get_reddit(search_terms="selection")

    red_data=Corpus(VectorSource(red_data$comment))
    red_data=tm_map(red_data,tolower)
    red_data=tm_map(red_data, removeNumbers)
    red_data=tm_map(red_data, removePunctuation)
    red_data=tm_map(red_data, stripWhitespace)
    red_data=tm_map(red_data,function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords()))
    red_data=tm_map(red_data,PlainTextDocument)
    red_data=tm_map(red_data, removeWords, c("like", "com", "www", "https", "http", "reddit", "just", "also","amp", "get","can", "will", "cobb", "county", "school","schools"))
    red_data<-Corpus(VectorSource(red_data))
})


  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    # plot it
    if(is.null(red_data)){
      NULL
    } else{
      col=brewer.pal(6,"Set2")
      wordcloud(red_data$comment, min.freq = 10, scale = c(5,0.5), rot.per = 0.25,

    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You should try to isolate the piece of code that is problematic because the current code is quite long and includes twitter related lines (which you mention to be working).

Comment: @GabrielDevillers thanks! I deleted everything but the Reddit-related code.